# How to populate a spinner based on the first two spinners using setOnItemSelectedListener

Tags: android

I have three spinners, the first is populated from the string xml file, the second should be populated based on the selection of the first and the third one based on the selection of the second.

I have search and tried several logic through the weekend with no success. After setting the setOnItemSelectedListener on the second and third spinners, none of them get populated.

Please help me. The sample code is provided below

```
public class Reg_Prop extends Activity implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {

//create reference
Button btnSave;
Spinner spinProvince, spinDistrict, spinLocal;
String spinPro, spinDist;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_reg_prop);

    Toast.makeText(this, "Please select the Province, District and Local Municipality where the " +
            "Property is located", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    //Initialise reference
    btnSave = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnSave);
    spinProvince = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinProvince);
    spinDistrict=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinDistrict);
    spinLocal=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinLocal);

    //set onClick Listener
    btnSave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        //@Overridde
        public void onClick(View v) {
            try {
                Intent ro = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(ro);
                //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Login button pressed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Login window could not display",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });

    //set onItemSelected Listener
    spinProvince.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
    spinDistrict.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

    switch (view.getId()){

        case R.id.spinProvince:
            spinPro = String.valueOf(spinProvince.getSelectedItem());
            Toast.makeText(this, spinPro, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            if(spinPro.contentEquals("Eastern Cape")){
                List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

                list.add("Select District/Metro *");
                list.add("Buffalo City");
                list.add("Nelson Mandela Bay");
                list.add("Alfred Nzo District");
                list.add("Amathole District");
                list.add("Chris Hani District");
                list.add("Joe Gqabi District");
                list.add("OR Tambo District");
                list.add("Cacadu District");

                final ArrayAdapter<String> districtAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this,
                        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
                districtAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                districtAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                spinDistrict.setAdapter(districtAdapter);
            }
       }
        else{
            Toast.makeText(this, "Please select the Province where the Property is located", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        break;

    case R.id.spinDistrict:
        spinDist = spinDistrict.getSelectedItem().toString();

        if(spinDist != "" && spinDist != "Select District/Metro *" || spinDist != "Select District *"){

            switch (spinDist){
                case "Buffalo City":
                    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

                    list.add("Select District/Metro *");
                    list.add("...");
                    list.add("N....");
                    list.add("Local");
                    list.add("Amathole District");
                    list.add("Chris Hani District");
                    list.add("Joe Gqabi District");
                    list.add("OR Tambo District");
                    list.add("Cacadu District");

                    final ArrayAdapter<String> localAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
                    localAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                    localAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    spinLocal.setAdapter(localAdapter);

                    break;
            }
        }
        else{
            Toast.makeText(this, "Please select the District Municipality", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        break;
     }
    }
 @Override
 public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

Toast.makeText(this, "Please select the Province, District and Local Municipality where the Property is located", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all those who read and tried to help me. I have finally solved the problem.

All I had to do was to place setOnItemSelectedListener for the first two spinners within the onCreate then use functions to populate the second and third spinner based on the selection. Note: the first spinner is populate from the string xml file.

Below is the sample code
inside onCreate:

```
 //set onItemSelected Listener
    spinProvince.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            String province = (String)parent.getItemAtPosition(position);

            if(province.matches("Eastern Cape")){
                spinPro = 1;
                populateDist();
            }
            else if(province.matches("Free State")){
                spinPro = 2;
                populateDist();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
            Toast.makeText(Reg_Prop.this, "Please select the Province where the Property is located", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    });

    spinDistrict.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener(){

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            String spinDist = (String)parent.getItemAtPosition(position);

            if(spinDist.matches("Buffalo City") && spinPro == 1){
                dist = 1;
                populateLocal();
            }
            else if(spinDist.matches("Nelson Mandela Bay") && spinPro == 1){
                dist = 2;
                populateLocal();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });
```

Functions to populate the spinners

```
void populateDist(){
    //Eatern Cape
    if(spinPro == 1){
        String [] ec = {"Select District/Metro *", "Buffalo City", "Nelson Mandela Bay",
                "Alfred Nzo District", "Amathole District", "Chris Hani District",
                "Joe Gqabi District", "OR Tambo District", "Cacadu District"};

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, ec);
        spinDistrict.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
    //Free State
    else if(spinPro == 2){
        String [] fs = {"Select District/Metro *", "Mangaung Metropolitan", "Fezile Dabi District",
                "Lejweleputswa District", "Thabo Mofutsanyana District", "Xhariep District"};

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter2 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, fs);
        spinDistrict.setAdapter(adapter2);
    }

}

void populateLocal(){
    //Baffalo City
    if(dist == 1){
        String [] bc = {"Buffalo City"};

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapterL1 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, bc);
        spinLocal.setAdapter(adapterL1);
    }
    //Nelson Mandela Bay
    else if(dist == 2){
        String [] nmb = {"Nelson Mandela Bay"};

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapterL2 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, nmb);
        spinLocal.setAdapter(adapterL2);
    }

}
```